# How to loop through a list of files that are sequentially named?

Tags: javascript, html

I placed a lot of pictures on one page:

```
<img src="1.gif" /><br>
<img src="2.gif" /><br>
<img src="3.gif" /><br>
<img src="4.gif" /><br>
<img src="5.gif" /><br>
<img src="6.gif" /><br>
<img src="7.gif" /><br>
<img src="8.gif" /><br>
<img src="9.gif" /><br>
<img src="10.gif" /><br>
<img src="11.gif" /><br>
<img src="12.gif" /><br>
<img src="13.gif" /><br>
<img src="14.gif" /><br>
<img src="15.gif" /><br>
<img src="16.gif" /><br>
<img src="17.gif" /><br>
<img src="18.gif" /><br>
<img src="19.gif" /><br>
<img src="20.gif" /><br>
<img src="21.gif" /><br>
<img src="22.gif" /><br>
<img src="23.gif" /><br>
<img src="24.gif" /><br>
<img src="25.gif" /><br>
```

Is there any other way to do it? Like a for loop in javascript?

I tried doing something with a javascript for loop (i+".gif").

Comment: Could you please provide some more information about your usecase? If you are talking about performance and images in the browser there are a lot of ways to help you out - or is it just about efficiency in your code?

Comment: A for loop would work, yes. `for (var i = 1; i<=25; ++i) html += '<img src="'+i+'.gif"/><br/>\n';` so if that didn't work, can you show the complete JS routine?

Comment: Note that `alt` attributes are required for valid html. If images are decorative only, use `alt=''`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
var imagesCount = 25;

// Create a fragment to collect the images
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

for (var i = 1; i <= imagesCount; i++) {
  var img = document.createElement('img');

  // give the image it's src based on i
  img.src = i + ".gif"; 

  fragment.appendChild(img);
}

// Insert the images in body
document.body.appendChild(fragment);
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps, see this complete example:

```js
var i;
var generatedImages = "";
for (i = 1; i <= 25; i++) {
  var srcString = i + ".gif";
  generatedImages += "<img src=" + srcString + " /><br>";
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = generatedImages;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div id="demo"></div>
  <script>
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
 <div id="images-container"></div>
```

**JS**

```
 var imagesData = [
    {src: "demo.gif", alt: "Demo"},
    ...
];

 var imagesContainer = document.getElementById("images-container");

 imagesData.forEach(function (data) {
     var img = new Image();
     img.src = data.src;
     img.alt = data.alt;

     imagesContainer.appendChild(img);
 });
```